# expected "spy" to be called at least once Vitest

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vite, vitest

I am getting error - expected "spy" to be called at least once, when calling

```
expect(log.warn).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

I do not understand why it is happening, because the function, which I am testing is calling that function `log.warn(.....)`

Unit test

```
describe('handleServerError', () => {
    it('should set error message in store and log the error', () => {
      vi.mock('common/helpers/server-error-message.js', async () => {
        const actual = await vi.importActual('common/helpers/server-error-message.js');
        return {
          ...actual,
          getErrorCodeFromEvent: () => 27001,
        };
      });
      actions.handleServerError(context);
      expect(context.commit).toHaveBeenCalledWith('setServerErrorCode', 27001);
      expect(log.warn).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
```

Vue store action

```
handleServerError(context, e) {
    log.warn(getServerErrorLogMessage('getLicenses', e));
    const code = getErrorCodeFromEvent(e);
    context.commit('setServerErrorCode', code);
  },
```

Maybe somebody had this situation and somehow overcame it?

I have tried numerous different variants from vitest documentation to test this, but none helped, also haven't found solution in stackoverflow

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this? Getting the same error

Comment: Did you find any solutions? Facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

try to spy on the function before you start your test

```
vi.spyOn(console, 'warn');
```

this essentially creates a mock for that function

https://vitest.dev/api/#vi-spyon

Comment: Thanks, but no success

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error on one of my test cases.

eg:-

```
const mockFn = vi.fn();

vi.mock('path', async (importActual) => {
  const actual = await importActual();

  return {
    ...actual,
    myFn: mockFn,
  };
});

test('should ...', async () => {
  render(<MyComponent />);

  await user.click(screen.getByRole('button', { name: 'Click me' }));

  expect(mockFn).toBeCalled();
});
```

Reason is my button hasn't clicked. Maybe a reason like it is disabled or has a pointer event none.